# Does tf.Print change values of a tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, printing, nan, tensor

I build a Tensorflow model at first and it can not work as the prediction always gets NaN. I learn this error from tensorflow logs.
So I try to debug with tf.Print(). My debug code is like below

```
tensor_a = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embed_a, indices_a)
tensor_b = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embed_b, indices_b)

tensor_a = tf.Print(tensor_a, [tensor_a, tf.reduce_mean(tensor_a)])
tensor_b = tf.Print(tensor_b, [tensor_b, tf.reduce_mean(tensor_b)])

logit = tf.matmul(tensor_a, tensor_b, transpose_a=False, transpose_b=True)
```

**tf.Print() is the only difference between two version.**

It is so weird that the debug code run and train well. Tensors printed cantain no Nan at all.

My TF version is 1.4.x. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No it doesn't. You might just run into instabilities due to unlucky/bad initializations. We can't say more because this is not a complete example.

Comment: @xdurch0 I have tried many times and tf.Print look like the most possible reason. Thanks anyway.